# django on appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am impressed with django.Am am currenty a java developer.I want to make some cool websites for myself but i want to host it in some third pary environmet.
Now the question is can i host the django application on appengine?If yes , how??
Are there any site built using django which are already hosted on appengine?

Answer (score 1):

Django-nonrel is the best and "official" way to run django on appengine. You can run django apps unmodified on AppEngine (as long as there are no complex joins or ManyToMany relationships)

You also now have access to the full django admin which really is the best part of django.

- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html
- http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

Answer (score 0):

- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html
- http://www.42topics.com/dumps/django/docs.html
- http://thomas.broxrost.com/2008/04/08/django-on-google-app-engine/

Yes, its quite possible. The only difference is, instead of using django's models and database api you simply need to use appengine's datastore api and models. Look at the above links for reference

Comment: This method is outdated. The "official" way to run django on appengine is using django-nonrel. It gives you the full django admin and you don't need to use different models and datastore apis like you used to.  http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html

Answer (score 0):

Appengine comes with built in Django, if you look under your (google_appengine/lib/django_1_3) lib dir you will see a few versions. You can define what version you want to be used in your app.yaml 
It isn't a full release of Django and if you do want to have full admin functionality of Django you might have to use something like nonrel but personally I would say its not necessary and you stand to gain more by getting to understand the underlying nosql structure of appengine, in particular the NDB model is very useful